# How do I go two characters left from the current position in file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, file-handling, seek

I am doing a project and in it I have to frequently edit a file from the position somewhere in the center. I want to go to the 2 characters left to the position from where the word 'rules' starts.

I have tried something like this:

```
with open("file.txt", "r+") as fh:
    content = fh.read()
    index = content.seek("rules") - 2
```

But it takes me to the two lines up instead of taking to two characters back.

This is how the file look:

```
rule1
rule2
rule3
rule4
.
.
.
.
rule100

rules are very good.
```

So, basically it is the last line of the file which starts with 'rules' and I want to go at the end of the line that is starting with 'rule100' and write a new line that will be something 'rule101' and save the file.

Comment: Do you have to read the whole file or are you just searching for the *rules* line?

Comment: I have to search for the 'rules', go back two characters and then write something and then save the file.

Comment: Basically, there is only one line that starts with 'rules' in the file. I want to go two characters back from the starting point of that line and then write something.

Comment: I have updated the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll firstly split the file into lines. 
- then we'll find the index where "rules" from the list.
From there - we'll insert the new rule we wish to insert.

Then join this list as `updated_content`.

We then seek to the beginning of the file and write it with `updated_content`

```
with open("text.txt", "r+") as fh:
    content = fh.read().splitlines()

    rulesIndex = content.index("rules are very good.")
    content.insert(rulesIndex - 1, "rule101")

    updated_content = "\n".join(content)

    fh.seek(0)
    fh.write(updated_content)
```

before

```
rule1
rule2
rule3
rule4
.
.
.
.
rule100

rules are very good.
```

after

```
rule1
rule2
rule3
rule4
.
.
.
.
rule100
rule101

rules are very good.
```

Comment: It gives me the `ValueError: substring not found`

Comment: Do you already have the position of rules? (This isn’t indicated in the question.

Comment: No, the file opens and it starts from the beginning of the file. I don't have the position of the 'rules' already.

Comment: getting `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seek'`

Answer (score 1):

If you only add content to the file you could use append. Then you won't need a special line and search for it. Just do:

```
with open("file.txt", "a") as fh:
    fh.append("rule101")
```